# Why can't I add an EmptyBorder to a custom JComponent?

Tags: java, swing

My code is unable to set the border of the custom JComponent object to `new EmptyBorder(50, 50, 50, 50)`. This is what it looks like on my monitor (as you can see, it clearly works for the JButton but not for the custom JComponent):

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class Sandbox
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Instantiate components needed.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        WideComponent wc = new WideComponent();
        JButton button = new JButton("Test");

        // Add borders
        EmptyBorder empty1 = new EmptyBorder(50, 50, 50, 50);
        wc.setBorder(empty1);
        EmptyBorder empty2 = new EmptyBorder(50, 50, 50, 50);
        button.setBorder(empty2);

        // Add stuff to panel
        panel.add(wc);
        panel.add(button);

        // Add panel to frame, show frame
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }
}

class WideComponent extends JComponent
{
    final int WIDTH = 500;
    final int HEIGHT = 150; 

    // drawing method
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    // JComponent sizing methods
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }
    public Dimension getMaximumSize() { return getPreferredSize(); }
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() { return getPreferredSize(); }    
}
```

Comment: Edited code to answer your question. It doesn't make a difference as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your borders are working fine -- but it's just that the empty border is being painted blue because you're painting the entire component and the border is part of that component. For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class Sandbox {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      frame.add(panel);
      WideComponent wc = new WideComponent();
      JButton button = new JButton("Test");

      wc.setBorder(createBorder());
      button.setBorder(createBorder());

      panel.add(wc);
      panel.add(button);

      frame.add(panel);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.pack();
   }

   private static Border createBorder() {
      Border innerBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red);
      int eb = 50;
      Border outerBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(eb, eb, eb, eb);
      Border comboBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outerBorder,
            innerBorder);
      return comboBorder;
   }
}

class WideComponent extends JComponent {
   final int WIDTH = 500;
   final int HEIGHT = 150;

   public WideComponent() {
      setOpaque(true);
   }

   // drawing method
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
       g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
       g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
   }

   // JComponent sizing methods
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
   }

   public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
      return getPreferredSize();
   }

   public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
      return getPreferredSize();
   }
}
```

If you want a blank border around your WideComponent, then nest it inside a JPanel, and give the border to the nesting JPanel. For instance, the code above could be changed with the addition of:

```
  JPanel nestingJPanel = new JPanel();
  nestingJPanel.add(new WideComponent());
  nestingJPanel.setBorder(createBorder());

  panel.add(wc);
  panel.add(button);
  panel.add(nestingJPanel);
```